# Can't construct a backward Newton polynomial

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numerical-methods

I've been playing around with this code for half a day now and I can only change the orientation of the curves at most. I've tried constructing a forward Newton polynomial using the same (albeit slightly adjusted due to direction reversal) algorithm, and it works fine. I've included them both for you to compare.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = -1
b = 1
N = 201
x = np.linspace(a, b, N)
n = [3, 7, 10, 20]

plotsPfw = [None, None, None, None]
fig1, ((plotsPfw[0], plotsPfw[1]),(plotsPfw[2], plotsPfw[3])) = plt.subplots(2,2, gridspec_kw = {'hspace': 0.5, 'wspace': 0.5})
plotsPbw = [None, None, None, None]
fig2, ((plotsPbw[0], plotsPbw[1]),(plotsPbw[2], plotsPbw[3])) = plt.subplots(2,2, gridspec_kw = {'hspace': 0.5, 'wspace': 0.5})

def Runge(x):
    return 1/(1+25*np.power(x,2))

def findif_forw(func, order, i):
    if order == 1:
        return (func[i+1] - func[i])
    else:
        return (findif_forw(func, order-1, i+1) - findif_forw(func, order-1, i))

def findif_backw(func, order, i):
    if order == 1:
        return (func[-1-i] - func[-1-i+1])
    else:
        return (findif_backw(func, order-1, i) - findif_backw(func, order-1, i-1))

def Newton_forw(xi, func, n):
    h = xi[1] - xi[0]
    N = func[0]
    q = (x - xi[0])/h
    Q = 1
    for i in range(1, n):
        Q *= (q - i + 1)/i
        N += findif_forw(func, i, 0)*Q
    return N

def Newton_backw(xi, func, n):
    h = xi[1] - xi[0]
    N = func[-1]
    q = (x - xi[-1])/h
    Q = 1
    for i in range(1, n):
        Q *= (q + i - 1)/i
        N += findif_backw(func, i, i)*Q
    return N

yRunge = Runge(x)

for i in range(0, len(n)):
    xi = np.linspace(a,b,n[i])
    yRungei = Runge(xi)
    yNewton_forw = Newton_forw(xi, yRungei, n[i])
    yNewton_backw = Newton_backw(xi, yRungei, n[i])
    plotsPfw[i].plot(x, yRunge, ':r', x, yNewton_forw, '-g', linewidth = 0.25)
    plotsPfw[i].set_title('n = {}'.format(n[i]))
    plotsPfw[i].set_xlabel('x')
    plotsPfw[i].set_ylabel('Runge, fwd P_{}(x)'.format(n[i]))
    plotsPbw[i].plot(x, yRunge, ':r', x, yNewton_backw, '-b', linewidth = 0.25)
    plotsPbw[i].set_title('n = {}'.format(n[i]))
    plotsPbw[i].set_xlabel('x')
    plotsPbw[i].set_ylabel('Runge, bkwd P_{}(x)'.format(n[i]))

plt.show()
```

The finite differences appear to be alright, after I checked them manually, the issue probably arises from the `q` part of the polynomial. This is the most apparent for case `n = 3` -- in forward formula after step 1 `Q` is an ascending (in direction of interpolation) slope, and after step 2 `Q` is a downward parabola shifted to the left, so on the far right end they appear to somewhat cancel each other out, leading to the interpolation polynomial graph going through the target graph `n` times.

In backward formula `Q` is almost always descending (again, in direction of interpolation), so the far left end becomes extremely unbalanced, which can be seen on the graph. I’ve tried the following:

- reverse the sign of value returned by order 1 finite difference
- reverse the sign of formula for q
- use q+i+1, q+i, q-i+1 in the Q polynomial

I believe either the interpolation method is *supposed* to become unbalanced towards the opposite end (and forward polynomial is wrong), or forward polynomial behaves as it is supposed to (and backward polynomial is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Your backward difference is very strange. Why is there a `-i` in the order 1 difference? You could repair that and further simplify both procedures by ending them on order 0 as

```
def findif_forw(func, order, i):
    return  func[i] if order == 0 else findif_forw(func, order-1, i+1) - findif_forw(func, order-1, i);

def findif_backw(func, order, i):
    return  func[i] if order == 0 else findif_backw(func, order-1, i) - findif_backw(func, order-1, i-1)
```

This will compute the backward differences with values from the initial index 
going backwards `order` terms. To get this to be the values from the end of the array, just simply call it with

```
        N += findif_backw(func, i, -1)*Q
```

---

Note that this is not very efficient as you recompute several of the intermediate differences.

The result is identical forward and backward as is to be expected from the symmetry of the function.
[image]